# Multiples div auto fill with same javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this js code that update 2 counters in 2 divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var div = document.getElementById('count');
        var yeardiv = document.getElementById('yearcount');

        function updateCount() {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 14200000 );
            div.innerHTML = count;

            d.setMonth( 0 );
            d.setDate( 1 );
            count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 14200000 )
            yeardiv.innerHTML = count;
        }

        updateCount();
        setInterval( updateCount, 14200000 );
    });
</script>
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="yearcount"></div>
...
...
...
<!-- again my divs-->
...
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="yearcount"></div>
```

My problem is that the first 2 divs are populated with the numbers generated by the script meanwhile the second 2 divs are empty.

How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First, you should not use the same id for multiple elements. Use classes instead

```
<div class="count"></div>
<div class="yearcount"></div>

<!-- other html -->

<div class="count"></div>
<div class="yearcount"></div>
```

Since it seems you are using jQuery, modify your script like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function updateCount() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 14200000 );
        jQuery('.count').html(count);

        d.setMonth( 0 );
        d.setDate( 1 );
        count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 14200000 )
        jQuery('.yearcount').html(count);
    }

    updateCount();
    setInterval( updateCount, 14200000 );
});
</script>
```

Let me explain this line of code:
`jQuery('.count').html(count);`

The first part `jQuery('.count')` means select all elements that have class count. The second part `.html(count)` means insert the value of the variable count.

*Additional notes on jQuery usage:

- In most cases, you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` which will shorten your code e.g. `$('.count').html(count)`
- instead of using `.html(count)`, you could also use `.text(count)` since you are not inserting any html tags
- you do not need to pass $ into the jQuery document ready callback function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of ID. An ID should only be used once in an HTML document. JavaScript knows this, and will only apply changes to the first instance of the ID. You should use a class instead.

Comment: Just change the Ids to classes, and update your JS to find the elements by class instead. I'm not going to do your work for you.